# ManyToManyField Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a response for ManyToManyField. For some reason it doesn't show my expected output when I change the model to ManyToManyField, but works well in ForeignKey.

**ProductSerializer**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    packages = PackageSerializer(many=True)
    coverage_amount_range = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

**AdvertismentSerializer**

```
class AdvertisementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Advertisements
        fields = ('id','title', 'product')
```

**Advertisements Model**

```
class Advertisements(models.Model):

    CATEGORY = (
        ('article', 'Article'),
        ('promo', 'Promo'),
    )

    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=30, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_image)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(DigiInsuree, blank=True, default=None, related_name='liked')
    view_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, default=2, null=True, related_name='+')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'

    @property
    def num_likes(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()
```

**Current JSON Response**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test Ad",
        "product": []
    }
]
```

**Expected JSON Response**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test Ad",
        "product": [
           "id" : 1,
           "product_name" : "test"
        ]
    }
]
```

[image: Product in Advertisement data]

I've tried following the tutorials in some platforms but still not displaying any product information. Thank you, hope you can help me

Comment: Please provide the "ProductSerializer" class.

Comment: Added the ProductSerializer Class

Answer (score 0):

Update your AdvertisementSerializer with the '**depth**' to get the details of field that does have a relation with another model.

```
class AdvertisementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Advertisements
        fields = ('id','title', 'product')
        depth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code as follows:

## models.py

```
class Advertisements(models.Model):

    CATEGORY = (
        ('article', 'Article'),
        ('promo', 'Promo'),
    )

    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY, max_length=30, null=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=upload_image)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(DigiInsuree, blank=True, default=None, related_name='liked')
    view_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0, null=True)
    
    # In this case, the related_name is set to 'products'.
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, default=2, null=True, related_name='products') 

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'app'

    @property
    def num_likes(self):
        return self.liked.all().count()
```

run command `python manage.py makemigrations` & `migrate`

## serializers.py

```py
class AdvertisementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # add source get products key
    product = ProductSerializer(source="product__products", many=True, read_only=True)  
    
    class Meta:
        model = Advertisements
        fields = ('id','title', 'product')
```

Comment: You can also use the `depth` attribute, but it can only be used for serialization and not for parsing data. @RagasImger